# SQl display rows as columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I need to convert the rows data to be displayed in columns for each user in MS Sql server:

```
+----------+----------+
| UserName | Products |
+----------+----------+
| User1    | Product1 |
| user1    | Product2 |
| user1    | Product3 |
| user2    | Product4 |
| User2    | Product3 |
| user3    | Product1 |
+----------+----------+
```

I need the output like below:

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| UserName |    p1     |    p2     |    p3     |
+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| User1    | Product1  | Product2  | Product3  |
| User2    | Product4  | Product3  |           |
| user3    | Product1  |           |           |
+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

also I don't know how to create a serial for columns unknown number of products for each user.
How we can achieve this and thanks in advance?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have tried to use pivot function but now working for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Comment: i'm using ms Sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2017 (or newer) you can aggregate all products for each `UserName` with `string_agg`, then you can split the result in columns using a bit of XML syntax.

Basically you build an xml version of your data and then you perform an xpath query to obtain the final result.

Here is an example of this technique:

```
declare @tmp table (UserName varchar(50), Products varchar(50))

insert into @tmp values
     ('User1','Product1')
    ,('user1','Product2')      
    ,('user1','Product3')
    ,('user2','Product4')
    ,('User2','Product3')
    ,('user3','Product1')

;WITH AggregatedProducts
AS (
    select UserName
    ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(string_agg(Products,'_'), '_', '</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS Segments  
    from @tmp
    group by UserName
    )
SELECT 
     UserName
    ,Segments.value(N'/x[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS p1
    ,Segments.value(N'/x[2]', 'varchar(50)') AS p2
    ,Segments.value(N'/x[3]', 'varchar(50)') AS p3
FROM AggregatedProducts
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank You for sharing this. it's working for me however i don't know is there any solution to use pivot function in my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the docs:

```sql
SELECT <non-pivoted column>,  
    [first pivoted column] AS <column name>,  
    [second pivoted column] AS <column name>,  
    ...  
    [last pivoted column] AS <column name>  
FROM  
    (<SELECT query that produces the data>)   
    AS <alias for the source query>  
PIVOT  
(  
    <aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)  
FOR   
[<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]   
    IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],  
    ... [last pivoted column])  
) AS <alias for the pivot table>  
<optional ORDER BY clause>;
```

Comment: I didn't have aggregation operation in my case. can you please apply the pivot function in my example or share the T-sql

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method that uses `string_agg` and then `parsename` function to split '.' delimited strings that are at most 128 characters and have at most 4 parts.

```
select 
username,
parsename(products,1) as p1,
parsename(products,2) as p2,
parsename(products,3) as p3,
from
(select username, string_agg(products,'.') within group (order by products desc) as products 
from your_table 
group by username) t
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0483a/9/0)